# Access a getter with funcion of Vuex in a component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a getter in Vuex, that has a function

```
GET_ATTR: (state) => attr => {
        if (state.data[attr]) {
            return state.data[attr]
        }
    }
```

Now, in a component I want to access to this value.

I have a computed method with:

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            test: 'form/GET_ATTR',
        }),
 ....
}
```

If I put in `<template><div>{{ test('name') }}</div></template>` it shows perfect.

But if I want to access to this in my component I get undefined all the time.

I try with

- `this.test('name')`
- `this.$store.getters['form/GET_ATTR']('name')`

I put it in `created()`, `mounted()`, `methods:{}` and always same thing

What I need to do to this?

Thanks

Comment: I put it in updated() and works, but I don't know if is recommend

Comment: Perhaps, you fill your store asynchronously, and until then `data` doesn't have anything?